# Exit bash script within while loop

Tags: linux, bash

How do you exit a script from within a find piped while loop?

E.g. following exit just exits the piped subshell:

```
find some_directory -type d|while read dir_name; do
  if [ -w "$dir_name" ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: You could not run it in a subshell `done < <(find some_directory -type d)`, probs wanna use `while IFS= read -r dir_name` to handle dodge filenames just incase as well.

Comment: Why so complicated? `find some_directory -type d ! -perm -u+w` will give you all non-writable directories in directory

Comment: @the.Legend how do you get the return value of that find? $? is 0 whether or not a file was found

Comment: there are few ways: if you only want exit status then just make it like  `find some_directory -type d ! -perm -u+w | egrep '.*' `

The return status will be 0 when something is found, and non-zero otherwise.

Alternatively you may play with `wc -l` or if you need to process files then just add `-exec {} \;` piece to `find` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the return status of the pipe:

```
if ! find some_directory -type d|while read dir_name; do
  if [ -w "$dir_name" ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
done; then exit 1; fi
```

Or, more simply:

```
 find some_directory -type d|while read dir_name; do
      [ -w "$dir_name" ] && exit 1
    done || exit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` an `exit` invoked in a subprocess will exit the subprocess but not the parent process.

In OP's code the pipeline - `find | while` - will run the `while` (and the subsequent `exit` invocation) within a subprocess, so if/when the `exit 1` is invoked the subprocess will be exited but not the parent process.

To allow the `exit` to apply at the top level we need to insure the `while` is not run within a subprocess.  Expanding on 123's comment:

```
while read -r dir_name; do
  if [ -w "$dir_name" ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
done < <(find some_directory -type d)
```

Note that the `<( )` construct ("process substitution") is not available in all shells, or even in bash when it's in sh-compatibility mode (i.e. when it's invoked as `sh` or `/bin/sh`). So be sure to use an explicit bash shebang (like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) in your script, and don't override it by running the script with the `sh` command.